# wrong day in Android Material DatePicker

Tags: android, date, datepicker, material-design, materialdatepicker

i'm trying to get te selected date from DatePicker but always i have one day less than the selected

For example, if I select 14/2/2022 i obtain 13/2/2022 and if I select 8/10/2018 i obtain 7/10/2018

This is my code:

```
private fun DatePickerSelected() {
    val picker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
        .setTitleText("Select date of birth")
        .setSelection(MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds())
        .build()

    picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
        val date = Date(picker.selection!!)
        Log.d("Date",date.toString())
        val dateString = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date)
        binding.edtBirthday.editText?.setText(dateString)
    }

    picker.show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, "BirthdayPicker")
}
```

Which is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: `todayInUtcMilliseconds` is there some day rounding here because of timezone conversions?

Comment: I take this code `.setSelection(MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds())` frome the material.io page

Comment: @Electrocode did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @keshavkowshik Yes. Just post the solution as answer.
Hope this can help you

Answer (score 2):

**I have the same issue in jetpack compose, material date picker ,**

**Root cause**
These date pickers return epoch time - AKA UTC (universal Coordinated Time)
e.g : if you click a date of 25 jan 2024 , these Api's will return epoch date and time of **25 jan 2024 00:00:00 AM ,

but problem arrives when you directly consume the data, because ,users aren't use UTC time,

**FIX**
convert the **UTC** -> **LocalTimeZone** before consuming data in api

```
fun epochToLocalTimeZoneConvertor(epoch: Long): Long{
val epochCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
epochCalendar.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
epochCalendar.timeInMillis = epoch
val converterCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
converterCalendar.set(
    epochCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
    epochCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
    epochCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE),
    epochCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
    epochCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
)
converterCalendar.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
return converterCalendar.timeInMillis }
```

**this solution is written in Kotlin,**

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution using calendar

```
picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
        val utc = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
        utc.timeInMillis = it
        //+1: The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0
        val stringData = "${utc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)}/${utc.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1}/${utc.get(Calendar.YEAR)}"
        binding.edtBirthday.editText?.setText(stringData)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the result from a call to picker is a timestamp in UTC timezone, all you gotta do is to convert it to yout local timezone.

Below is the logic to show a DialogPicker with a listener that converts the result from UTC to the device´s time zone:

```
  // create the dialog picker
    val picker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder
        .datePicker()
        .setSelection(initialDate)// initial date can be a date on local timezone
        .setTitleText("")
        .build()

    picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
        // create an object with a matching timezone
        val utcDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(it), ZoneOffset.UTC)
        // create an object converting from UTC to the device´s timezone
        val myTimeZoneDate = ZonedDateTime.of(utcDate, ZoneId.systemDefault())
        // get the long timestamp to use as you want
        val myTimeZoneDateLong = myTimeZoneDate.toInstant().toEpochMilli()

    }
    
    // show picker
    picker.show(parentFragmentManager, "tag")
```

Remember: You should always handle Date as time zoneless what includes store it in a database, using it to synchronize data or make comparations. The only exception is when you show it to user in this case obviously it should be converted to local timezone. Not doing this will cause really big problems if your users use your app with diferent timezones.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for M3. 
Thank you. I was missing the ZoneDateTime.of() portion +  was using systemDefault  in utcDate calc, when it should have been UTC

Answer (score -1):

try this code, add one day

```
 date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1)
```